# Converting a POST array to its proper datatypes

Tags: r, casting

I am sending a json array by POST to an R script.  The array looks like this:

```
POST$samples=
 {"DIW blank":["23.36"],
  "DA-f 1000 20081118":["6.31"],
  "1294 RM DA Biosense Nov 2008":["6.28"],
  "1334 RM DA Biosense Nov 2008":["6.28","22.84"],
  "1422 RM DA Biosense Nov 2008":["6.29"]
 }
```

When I convert that from json in R, I get this list:

```
$`DIW blank`
[1] "23.36"

$`DA-f 1000 20081118`
[1] "6.31"

$`1294 RM DA Biosense Nov 2008`
[1] "6.28"

$`1334 RM DA Biosense Nov 2008`
[1] "6.28"  "22.84"

$`1422 RM DA Biosense Nov 2008`
[1] "6.29"
```

What I'd like is for all the number vectors to actually be numbers.  Do I have to foreach through the list with as.numeric, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Well, it's only one line with `lapply`, right?

Comment: DO you need character data in the JSON code? x <- '{"DIW blank":[23.36],"DA-f 1000 20081118":[6.31]}' and fromJSON(x) give you what you want.

Comment: @jverzani: the issue is that anything posted to a script is always character data.  If I had a choice about the presense of quotes, I'd leave them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one line bit of code that joran was (perhaps) thinking about:

```
lis2  <- lapply(lis1, as.numeric)
```

Comment: thank you! I usually don't have to work with lists and they always flummox me.